# Invalid regular expression flag b on property list sending AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run the code:

```
runrequest = function () {
 $.ajax({
 url: 'ajax.php',
 success: function(data) {
  proccessrequest(true,eval(data));
  },
 error: function(data) {
  proccessrequest(false,eval(data));
  }
 });
 }
```

For some reason whenever I run this code Firebug gives me the error:

```
invalid regular expression flag b
},
```

This is referring to the }, after the success function. I am clueless of why this wouldn't work.

EDIT: The return data is ajax is JSON. The json is wrapped in parentheses

Comment: It would be interesting what `data` is.

Comment: agreed, what exactly is being returned by ajax.php??

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely getting an error back.  The error message has the invalid expression.

For example if your error contains bold  `Warning: < /b >` then there it is.

Answer (score 0):

The line number is off here, more likely your error is `eval(data)`, and that data has something like:

```
var regex = /expr/b
```

in there, which isn't a valid flag.

Comment: The data is json. The response would be something like ({'foo':'blah','blahblah':{'blah':'blah'}})

Comment: @Eric - you sure there's no regex definition in there?